# Entropy book recommendations: K-property & (weak) Bernoulli property

Tags: book-recommendation, entropy, ergodic-theory

I want to study K-property and -automorphisms, Bernoulli property, weak Bernoulli property and connections between them and entropy, but can't find any literature that covers these topics, so I'm asking for recommendations.
Thanks!

Comment: Ornstein's program essentially answers all entropic questions about the (weak) Bernoulli property, since in their paper "On isomorphism of weak Bernoulli transformations" the authors Ornstein and Friedman proved entropy is a complete invariant for weak Bernoulli transformations (and for strong transforms it is the classical Ornstein isomorphism theorem). I can't say I'm familiar with a book on $K$-systems, though there are plenty of scattered results in papers

Comment: Well, I just got a bit tired of going through all the papers - I thought this piece of theory is already classic enough to be rigorously written down)

Comment: There very well might be a recent (in a relative sense) book containing all (or at least a good portion) of this, I merely meant that I haven't encountered such a book yet nor seen such a citation. Ornstein theory will definitely be outlined in a number of recent texts, but I'd be surprised to see more than a mention of $K$-systems in any text I've yet encountered. I share your thoughts on the matter now becoming classical, and likewise hope someone else here can enlighten us on an updated text containing the state of the art :)

Comment: For lack of better options, I could recommend Ergodic theory by Kornfeld, Sinay and Fomin